# ¿Por qué no llegan las notificaciones desde la consola de Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

En la consola de Firebase creé un nuevo proyecto con el SHA1 y el nombre de mi proyecto en Android.

Agregué las dependencias en el gradle y los permisos de internet en el manifest y también la siguiente clase:

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
   {
     @Override
      public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) 
     {
       Log.e("FIREBASE", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
     }
   }
```

Y en el manifest agregue de la siguiente manera:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Ejecuto mi aplicación y envío las notificaciones desde la consola de Firebase, pero no me llegan, ¿Qué podría agregarle? o ¿cual es mi error?

Comment: Necesito que me enseñes el *app.gradle* y el *project.gradle*, gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Falta el servicio que extiende de FirebaseInstanceIdService que se encarga de obtener el token de Firebase Notifications y vincularlo con tu sesión. Fuente : https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-device#set_up_the_sdk

Tienes que agregar en el manifest:

```
<service android:name=".service.FCMIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

y la clase

```
public class FCMIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
// hacer algo adicional si lo quiero guardar, pero no hace falta.
    }
}
```